# Flash - Clip is repeating and not stopping

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I made a memory game. There is some fish in a game, moving randomly until a stop. Player has to try remembering first one's movements. I converted a fish object to `button` so it's not a `movieClip`.

The fish appear perfectly but won't stop. I use `stop();` within the last frame but it's not working. How I can stop this?

I use this **code for Fish 1**

```
var xsekseni:Number=10;

var ysekseni:Number=14;

var speedy:Number=75;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,bhareket);

function bhareket(oly:Event) {

    balik1.x+=xsekseni;

    balik1.y+=ysekseni;

    if ((balik1.x>=stage.stageWidth-balik1.width/2)|| (balik1.x <= balik1.width/2 )) {

        xsekseni*=-1;

    }

    if ((balik1.y>=stage.stageHeight-balik1.height/2)|| (balik1.y <= balik1.height/2 )) {

        ysekseni*=-1;

    }

}



var MovieArray:Array = [balik1];

for (var j:uint = 0; j < MovieArray.length; j++) {

MovieArray[j].x = Math.floor( Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth - MovieArray[j].width) );

MovieArray[j].y = Math.floor( Math.random()*(stage.stageHeight - MovieArray[j].height) );

}

function MovieRandomPositon():void {

MovieRandomPositon();

}
```

**code for Fish 2**

```
var mvkk:Array = [balik2];

for (var i:uint = 0; i < mvkk.length; i++) {

mvkk[i].x = Math.floor( Math.random()*(stage.stageWidth - mvkk[i].width) );

mvkk[i].y = Math.floor( Math.random()*(stage.stageHeight - mvkk[i].height) );

}

function MovieR():void {

MovieR();

}



var xekseni:Number=10;

var yekseni:Number=7;

var speed:Number=75;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,hareket);

function hareket(oly:Event) {

    balik2.x+=xekseni;

    balik2.y+=yekseni;

    if ((balik2.x>=stage.stageWidth-balik2.width/2)|| (balik2.x <= balik2.width/2 )) {

        xekseni*=-1;

    }

    if ((balik2.y>=stage.stageHeight-balik2.height/2)|| (balik2.y <= balik2.height/2 )) {

        yekseni*=-1;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you moving both Fish by code only? These two lines might be causing the same movement you want to stop...

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bhareket);
```

and

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hareket);
```

I haven't put code in different frames for many years so I can't be sure if the below code will work. Actually it would be correct if your code was all in one place but if lucky, it might work on your setup...

Try using code below on last frame.

```
stop();
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hareket);
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bhareket);
```

Comment: Thank you Vc that's work.How I can set the "true" to first fish ?

Comment: Explain meaning of _set the "true"_... Maybe delete the line you don't need for stopping?.. `ENTER_FRAME` is what makes movement so use `addEvent...` to make movement true then later use `removeEvent...` to make movement false. Also instead of all the `stage`, you can attach event directly to one object like this : `balik1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bhareket);` this way it's easier to see which object you are commanding to stop or start.

Comment: Thank I'm gonna also try that.

Comment: So I mean right selection.

A few fish come to the screen and after a while the other fishes come in.After a while the stage is stopped and the player is trying to guess the first fishes.I need a code to say that the chosen fish is wrong or true.this what I'm trying to do.