# How I can create more than right selection. ( Flash )

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

A few fish come to the screen and after a while the other fishes come in.Then a while the stage is stopped and the player is trying to guess the first fishes.How can I create code to say that the chosen fish is wrong or true.For example:The first come 3 fishes it's correct and after then came fishes wrong.Player guess right all the fishes and earn coins or display win text bla bla..

Comment: look into variables and conditions. For example, declar a variable to keep track of actual fishes and another one for the player's guess. On the event that makes sense for your gameplay use an ```if``` statement to check if the guessed value is equal to the correct value or not to display the appropriate content

Comment: What structure have you used to control how the fish are selected (the order/sequence they come in? Which fish are first?). In other words, how do you, as the developer select the sequence of fish to be, for example, blue, blue, green, yellow, red, blue? Is it random? Are you animating them on the timeline? Are you pulling them in order from an array and moving them with actionscript code? Knowing what structure you are using will make it easier for us to show you how to implement a solution.

Comment: @NealDavis I selected to sequence of the fish at timeline.So yes I animated.I was using as3 random function for the display on the screen.You can see at this link.Thanks  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41503315/flash-clip-is-repeating-and-not-stopping/41504251?noredirect=1#comment70214746_41504251

Comment: And how does the player respond? How do they answer the sequence they remember?

Comment: @NealDavis This is a memory game.Fishes (it's buttons ) display on the screen and stop then other fishes ( a wrong fishes ) display.After a while stops all the scene and player choose ( click ) right fishes.So all I need: if button 1 + button2 clicked then go to bla bla.. All in the one order....This is a such as example...[link](http://www.mindgames.com/game/Fruit+Flip)]